# .htaccess rewrite all HTTPS to HTTP except one page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I want all HTTPS to be rewritten to HTTP except one page. The problem is, there are pages containing a query string and other pages containing a page path. Only one page containing a certain querystring should NOT be rewritten. I can't get it together:

```
Should be rewritten:
https://domain.tld/index.php?id=1
https://domain.tld/index.php?id=2
[...and so on...]
https://domain.tld/path/page1.html
https://domain.tld/path/page2.html
[...and so on...]

Should NOT be rewritten:
https://domain.tld/index.php?id=999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule to redirect all but one mentioned URI to `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+index\.php\?id=999[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

Comment: Fine! But i meant changing all HTTPS to HTTP except one. Should be possible by negating your example, isnt' it?

Comment: But this works only for URLs containing a query string like "id=xyz". An url like https://domain.tld/path/page.html is rewritten wrong to http://domain.tld/index.php

Comment: Sorry: Your code works, mistake was on my site - i had to place the code directly below "Rewrite engine on" to be executed before any other rules ;)

Comment: Smooth answer... I wouldn't have thought of the `NE`, great call. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81, yes `NE` is very handy when using `R` when URL has special characters.